# Trouble sorting morse code into Binary Tree

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand why my `Insert(string key)` isn't sorting the morse code (a-z 0-9) correctly. From the output it seems that it is sorting the exact same morse code. Which leads me to believe that the issue is my Insert function, since the morse code getting fed to the Insert function doesn't contain any duplicates.

```c
void BST::Insert(node *&start, string key){
    if (start == NULL) {
        start = new node;
        start->code = key;
        start->left = start->right = NULL;
        printf("Inserting Morse Code -> %s\n",key.c_str());
    }
}


void BST::Insert(string key) {
    node **start = &root;
    if (*start != NULL) {
        for(int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            assert(*start);
            if (key[i] == '.') {
                start = &((*start)->left);
            } else if (key[i] == '-') {
                 start = &((*start)->right);
            }else {
                break;
            }
            Insert(*start, key);
       }
    } else {
        Insert(root, key);
    }
}
```

The output I'm producing is:

```
Inserting Morse Code -> .-
Inserting Morse Code -> -...
Inserting Morse Code -> -...
Inserting Morse Code -> -...
Inserting Morse Code -> -...
Inserting Morse Code -> -.-.
Inserting Morse Code -> -.-.
Inserting Morse Code -> .
Inserting Morse Code -> ..-.
Inserting Morse Code -> ..-.
Inserting Morse Code -> ..-.
Inserting Morse Code -> --.
Inserting Morse Code -> --.
Inserting Morse Code -> ....
Inserting Morse Code -> ....
Inserting Morse Code -> .---
Inserting Morse Code -> .---
Inserting Morse Code -> .---
Inserting Morse Code -> .-..
Inserting Morse Code -> .-..
Inserting Morse Code -> ---
Inserting Morse Code -> .--.
Inserting Morse Code -> --.-
Inserting Morse Code -> ...-
Inserting Morse Code -> -..-
Inserting Morse Code -> -.--
Inserting Morse Code -> --..
Inserting Morse Code -> ----
Inserting Morse Code -> .----
Inserting Morse Code -> ..---
Inserting Morse Code -> ..---
Inserting Morse Code -> ...--
Inserting Morse Code -> ....-
Inserting Morse Code -> .....
Inserting Morse Code -> -....
Inserting Morse Code -> --...
Inserting Morse Code -> ---..
Inserting Morse Code -> ---..
Inserting Morse Code -> ----.
.....
....
....-
....
...-
...--
..-.
..-.
..-.
..---
..---
.
.-..
.-..
.---
.--.
.---
.---
.----
.-
-....
-...
-...
-..-
-...
-.-.
-.-.
-.--
-...
--...
--..
--.
--.-
--.
---..
---..
---
----.
----
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to sort intputs into a _binary search tree_, rather than decoding inputs using the [binary tree representation of morse code](https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/moler/exm/chapters/morse.pdf)?

Comment: Perhaps you should include the output you were expecting? Because the output I see is a good match for the posted code. And that's all I have to go on for what's expected. Do you really want me probing your mind to read your thoughts as to what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the problem ?

Your `Insert(*start, key);` is in the body of the `for` loop that repeats until the length of string is reached.  So when inserting a code of 4 morse digits, your'll insert 4 times.  The only exception is for the first insert, since this is a branch without `for` loop.

#### How to solve it ?

You need to compare the key with the current code to decide whether you insert left or right.  Currently you are trying to solve this by mixing iterative and recursive approach that is not suitable.

A better approach would be to use a public front-end function:

```
void BST::Insert(string key) {
    Insert(root, key); 
    }
```

And make the auxiliary function private and recursive:

```
void BST::Insert(node *&start, string key){
    if (start == nullptr) {    // new node must be created
        start = new node;
        start->code = key;    // better move this to the node constructor
        start->left = start->right = nullptr;  // same here
        printf("Inserting Morse Code -> %s\n",key.c_str());
    }
    else if (start->code<key) 
        Insert (start->left, key); 
    else if (start->code>key) 
        Insert (start->right, key); 
    else cout<<"Duplicate"<<endl;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/ohMzVU)

You may want to revise the way the order is assessed.

Now, as it's always the same key, you could pass the key as const string& to avoid unnecessary copies in the recursions.

Comment: Thank you for the help, your explanation made me understand the issue. As for the order its in, I'm already on that. Thanks again!